# Arranging QMenu items horizontally

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I have created a custom menu as a Popup. When I use addAction the items are arranged vertically. Is it possible to align the QMenu items horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's posible. You can implement your own [QWidgetAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidgetaction.html) and add QToolButton in an horizontal layout do display the action:

```
class MyAction : public QWidgetAction
{
public:
    MyAction( QObject * parent ) :QWidgetAction(arent) {}
    void releaseWidget(QWidget * widget) {widget->deleteLater();}
    QWidget * requestWidget ( QWidget * parent ) {   
        //Then implement your own widget
        QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
        widget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout(wdiget));
        widget->layout()->addWidget(new QToolButton("Example"));
        return widget;
    }
};
```

Other way its to set up the widget manually without subclassing:

```
QWidgetAction * wa = new QWidgetAction(this);    
wa->setDefaultWidget(new QPushButton("Default")); // Example a pushbutton
```

And then use it in your QMenu, you can add other actions or different widgets:

```
MyWidgetAction *mwa = new MyWidgetAction(this);  //3
ui->menuBar->addAction( mwa ); //3 - noop. nothing added to menu bar
```